# iframe & removing scroll bars

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, css, html, iframe

Hi I have an iframe and I am trying to hide the scroll bar however with the code I'm assuming it doesn't seem to disappear. Any suggestions?

[image]

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 800px;">
<iframe scrolling="no" src="https://bp365.sharepoint.com/sites/COP/DataScience/SitePages/News.aspx" style="border: 0px none; width: 750px; height: 500px; ">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: edit max-width: 900px;

Comment: It still appears. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Check or increase the script editor width by editing the webpart..

Comment: still didnt work...

Answer (score 0):

We can add react script editor web part into News.aspx page, and add the style below into the web part.

```
<style>
div[class^='scrollRegion_']{
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
</style>
```

The React Script Editor solution from here:

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately due to limitations on modern pages the modern script web-part is restricted and not accessible to complete from the solution you have provided

Comment: Did you install the react script editor web part?

Comment: Unfortunately  this isn't available to download due to admin restrictions from the client

Comment: Follow the article http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2017/12/install-spfx-react-script-editor-web.html to install it.